# can't set Tablayout title in single line

Tags: java, android, android-layout

In my design
1.Create a viewPager with 4 page.
2.Create the Tablayout and setup with viewpager.
[image]
In android device whose screen size is large then tab title display in single line.
If screen size is small the tab tile is wraped and display in two line.
I want to display all tab title in single line.
Thanks in advance.

Update:

[image]

Update 2:
[image]

Comment: Post your xml file here

Comment: <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/toolbar_background"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"/>
  
  
  //set viewpager to tabLayout 
  tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

Answer (score 6):

[image]Hope this does for you as it worked for me just fine.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Above is the code I used

```
app:tabMode="scrollable"
```

this helps when the text in `tabItem` is little long than required it certainly adjust the layout accordingly.[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try this..make width as `match_parent` and The `tabMode` and `tabGravity` attributes does the trick. This lets the labels span as long as need be and scrolling.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
       android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:tabMode="scrollable"
       app:tabGravity="fill"
       app:tabIndicatorHeight="5dp"
    />
```

Comment: after update the tabLayout xml ,title displayed in single line.but there is some space after last tab.

Comment: @AlthafAhamed like what space?

Comment: the tablayout width is not fit to screen width.

Comment: @AlthafAhamed please post a screenshot so that it will be clear what the issue is

Comment: Add this and check - app:tabPaddingStart="-1dp"
app:tabPaddingEnd="-1dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

Comment: Space is increased and text width not fit to screen.

Comment: Make app:tabGravity="center" and remove app:tabPaddingStart="-1dp" app:tabPaddingEnd="-1dp" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

Comment: Still not fixed,display looks like second screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

Use **setTabGravity** property with your **TabLayout**

**.xml**

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**.Class**

```
tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
```

Comment: Hey, @Althaf try with this